# How do I print breadcrumbs on page.html.twig?

Tags: 8, theming

How do I print breadcrumbs on page.html.twig?

I tried `{{ breadcrumb }}` but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The breadcrumbs are now a block. You have to go to the block layout and put them into a region. If you want `{{ page.breadcrumb }}` to work, you have to put them into the region breadcrumb.

This is the same for site branding and title, they all have moved into blocks.

Comment: Thx. Now everything is clear!

Answer (score 1):

As it is done in the [page.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21templates%21page.html.twig/8) template used by Drupal 8, you simply use `{{ page.breadcrumb }}`.

In Drupal 8, the breadcrumb is now a region of the page, together the following ones.

- page.header: Items for the header region
- page.primary_menu: Items for the primary menu region
- page.secondary_menu: Items for the secondary menu region
- page.highlighted: Items for the highlighted content region
- page.help: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages
- page.content: The main content of the current page
- page.sidebar_first: Items for the first sidebar
- page.sidebar_second: Items for the second sidebar
- page.footer: Items for the footer region

Comment: Yes. I know that. But this is also not working.

Comment: Then something else is wrong.